# Why can't I accept an answer here on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question 11 hours ago, and someone has answered correctly, so I want to mark it as accepted.

*To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in* from:

[https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:%7E:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time).

Yet there is no 'check mark', only a flag to flag an issue.

Comment: ...have you waited 15 minutes or longer since you posted the question?

Comment: If you do want to accept the comment as an answer, ask the user to post it as an answer in the comments (on your question). Make sure you ping the user in the comment you made.Then if/when the user posts it as an answer, you can accept it.

Comment: FWIW, "why" questions are very hard to answer because it's often unclear what you are actually asking. Why the designers chose this? Why it has a technical advantage? Why it has a usability advantage? Why the code works like this? And so on. This is especially the case when it's not clear whether the code is understood at face value to begin with – for example by asking about "double sq brackets" instead of the very fundamental, well-known type that this represents. Getting comment "answers" often indicates that people do not feel the question is well-defined enough to provide proper answers.

Comment: 11 hours ago your question you asked 15 hours ago didn’t have an answer only an unnecessary comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the answer is not a real answer, it's just a comment under your question.

Comment: The “answer” to that question, which is a comment, should also be flagged as being unnecessary at this point in my opinion.